# Multiple sorting, get first count of sorting

Tags: magento2, product-sorting, featured-product, count

I want to know the count of the first sort of listing product in categories. I override

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

to

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Rewrite/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

to be able to add another sort. The actual code is:

```
/**
 * Set collection to pager
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'position') {
            $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                $this->getCurrentOrder(),
                $this->getCurrentDirection()
            );
        } else {
            $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('featured_category','asc');
            $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                $this->getCurrentOrder(),
                $this->getCurrentDirection()
            );
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I want to know the "featured_category" count to validate the maximum number of products for this sort.

Any ideas, Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch collection count by the following methods.

```
$collection->getSize();
```

OR

```
$collection->count();
```

You can fetch collection count while using pagination in the following way.

```
$collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
$collection->setCurPage($page);
$collection->clear(); // Clear your collection.
$collection->getSize();// Give you correct count ignoring above pagination.
```

You can fetch collection count while using limit & offset in the following way.

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit($pageSize,$offset);
$collection->clear(); //This clear collection & give you correct collection total.**  
$collection->getSize(); //Now you will get correct collection total even if you have pagination code.
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the count of the first sort $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('featured_category','asc'); products count with Attribute "featured_category" value true, is it possible with addAtributeToSort method?

Comment: According to your above comment featured_category attribute has value like true/false, Yes/No in the backend? can you confirm the attribute value? Basically addAtributeToSort works on numeric attribute values only.

Comment: Yes, the attribute has value true/false, however this works, but i need maximum number of items with value true (in first sort), i wiil try with numeric attribute value and i will add the attribute to "Products in Category" column. I will bring new comments

Comment: I had created an numeric attribute and it works! Thanks